# Touch sensitive surface above leds

Tags: arduino, led, touchscreen, touch-panel

So I'm currently working on a box which should dim my lights based on a touch surface on top of the box. To indicate the light brightness I want to place a ws2812b ledstrip under a layer of white epoxy on the top of the box. Because of aesthetic reasons I planning to have the touch sensitive part (maybe TTP223 sensors in a row?, I would like to avoid a classic touch screen because of the pain to make it work with the Arduino IDE) on top of the LEDs but without blocking the light of the LEDs.
To process the Input and dim my Philips Hue Lights I'm using a NodeMCU microcontroller.

Any ideas or recommendations regarding the touch surface? Will the TTP223 sensors detect the touch when it's covered with the led and an epoxy layer? Are there any other sensors that should do the trick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a touchscreen overlay without the LCD.

Comment: Perhaps a row of capacitive sensors behind the LEDs